# Implement in Scheme a recursive function computing binomial coefficients

Tags: scheme

I need to take this recursive function and convert it into scheme

```
int B(int n, int k)

{ if ((n >= 0) && (k >= 0) && (n >= k))

if ((k == 0) || (k == n)) return 1;

else return B(n-1, k-1) + B(n-1, k);

else return 0; /∗ actually undefined here ∗/
}
```

I wrote this in scheme is this correct?

```
Define B (n, k)

 if(((>= n 0)>= k 0) >= n k))

    B(n-1, k-1) + B(n-1, k)
```

Answer (score 2):

The sample C (or similar) code doesn't look right to begin with (please fix the indentation and use braces!), and your translation to Scheme is incorrect. Clearly you didn't test it, it has some very obvious errors and it won't compile... Anyway, a straightforward translation will look more like this:

```
(define (B n k)
  (if (and (>= n 0) (>= k 0) (>= n k))
      (if (or (= k 0) (= k n))
          1
          (+ (B (- n 1) (- k 1))
             (B (- n 1) k)))
      0))
```

Or a bit more idiomatic:

```
(define (B n k)
  (if (>= n k 0)
      (if (or (zero? k) (= k n))
          1
          (+ (B (sub1 n) (sub1 k))
             (B (sub1 n) k)))
      0))
```

Comment: amazing !@#@#$#@! you put an effort in to help, and someone downvotes you - without any explanations. I know what *I* would feel....